# how can I use both sub font family in my app?

Tags: flutter

I am using font-family called "FFShamelFamily". I added two sub-font families as shown in the picture below. When I run my app, it uses the first sub-fontFamily: "SansOneBook" only. I try to use fontWeight to make use of the second sub-fontFamily:"SansOneBold" but it doesn't show. I mean that I want to use both of the sub-FontFamily, the bold one for titles and the other one for any text in the app. How can I do it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using a custom font you need to specify which FontFamily to use on a TextStyle. Your “sub” font FFShamelFamily-SansOneBold is correctly set up in your pubspec.yaml as a weight variation of the same Font Family.

To use it in a textStyle you simply have to use the weight you set it to with the correct family name:

```dart
Text(
 “Hello, world”,
 style: TextStyle(
   fontFamily: “FFShamelFamily”,
   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
 ),
)
```

Please check the [official flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts) for using custom fonts to learn more.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. I mentioned in my question that I use fontWeight but in vein.

Comment: Are you getting any other kind of error in the flutter console?

Comment: No, no errors in my console